# IIS url rewrite module 2 cannot be installed On vista Home Basic

Tags: visual-studio, cakephp, iis

My problem is:

iis url rewrite module 2 cannot be installed On vista Home Basic

My real SO is Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP1 and in other computer with similar or same specifications works correctly.

[IIS Rewrite Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6gHa.png)

Answer (score 0):

IIS URlRewrite  Module 2 can be installed Windows Vista Service Pack 1 as per [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7435)

> Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 Datacenter,
>   Windows Server 2008 Datacenter without Hyper-V, Windows Server 2008
>   Enterprise, Windows Server 2008 Enterprise without Hyper-V, Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, Windows Server 2008
>   R2 Enterprise, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2
>   Standard, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008
>   Standard, Windows Server 2008 Standard without Hyper-V, Windows Server
>   2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, **Windows Vista Service Pack 1**, Windows
>   Web Server 2008, Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Do you have the service pack 1 installed?

Comment: My error is in the operating system, in the picture my SO is Windows 7 SP1 but the error continue detect wrong the SO